# Array duplicated how to make a single

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have for example var $test and the output is below. You can see its duplicated.
How can i make it not duplicated? Is there any function for it?

```
Array ( 
       [title] => Array ( 
             [0] => this field is required 
             [1] => must be longer than2 
       ) 
       [subtitle] => Array ( 
             [0] => this field is required 
             [1] => must be longer than2 
       ) 
)    
Array ( 
       [title] => Array ( 
             [0] => this field is required 
             [1] => must be longer than2 
       ) 
       [subtitle] => Array ( 
             [0] => this field is required 
             [1] => must be longer than2 
       ) 
)
```

Expected result:

```
Array ( 
       [title] => Array ( 
             [0] => this field is required 
             [1] => must be longer than2 
       ) 
       [subtitle] => Array ( 
             [0] => this field is required 
             [1] => must be longer than2 
       ) 
)
```

Comment: did you at least try [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) ?

Comment: It's a long shot, but have you tried this one? http://dk1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Yes, array_unique($test); doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function intersect($data=NULL){
      if(!empty($data)){$crashed = array();
      $crashed2 = array();
      foreach($data[0] as $key=>$val){ 
             if(!is_array($val)){
               $crashed[$key] = in_array($val,$data[1]);//return true if crashed(intersect)
              }else{
               $crashed2[$key] = intersect(array($val,$data[1]));
              }
      $crashed = array_merge($crashed,$crashed2);
       }
    }return $crashed;
   }
   $intersect =intersect(array($array1,$array2));
   print_r($intersect);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  ;

```
$unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
print_r($unique);
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/30731)

Comment: @ Baba sorry, wrong array, i have updated it. If i print_r then i get this array. The previous didnt work.

Comment: add your expected result to your question

Comment: Done Baba, just a singele, i hope you can help!

Comment: With that expected result .. the code i added would still work .... did you even try it first ?

Comment: Yes, he gives back 2 times   Array ( [title] => Array ( [0] => this field is required [1] => must be longer than2 ) )

Comment: Is that not what is in your expected result .. learn to help your self .. http://eval.in/30732 matches exactly what was in your expected result

Comment: In your array is an comma for the next, not in my example. And you have put 2 arrays i  in one thats the differents i see.